# ie7 child block element expands and disregards parent padding

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

I have a block element inside another block element which has a bottom padding (the parent). The child element expands its height 100% at the same time eating/overlapping the bottom padding of the parent as if there's no padding at all.

What could be triggering this behavior?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<span class="boxTop">
    <span class="boxBottom">
        <span class="boxLeft">
            <span class="boxRight">
                <span class="box">
                    Content goes here
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.infoBox .boxTop {
padding:20px 0 0 0;
display:block;
background:transparent url(images/infobox-top.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
.infoBox .boxBottom {
padding:0 0 20px 0;
display:block;
background:transparent url(images/infobox-bottom.png) repeat-x 0 bottom;
}
.infoBox .boxLeft {
padding:0 0 0 20px;
display:block;
background:transparent url(images/infobox-left.png) repeat-y left 0;
}
.infoBox .boxRight {
padding:0 20px 0 0;
display:block;
background:transparent url(images/infobox-right.png) repeat-y right 0;
}
```

Here's how it looks like in ie7:

here's boxBottom: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v466/nemesis2k4/Forum%20Posts/boxbottom.jpg

and here's boxLeft and boxRight, both expanding and overlapping/disregarding boxBottom's padding: 
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v466/nemesis2k4/Forum%20Posts/boxleft.jpg
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v466/nemesis2k4/Forum%20Posts/boxright.jpg

Comment: please show your code for better understanding

Comment: Since your HTML sample code contains five elements, it's very difficult to understand which elements you are refering to a "parent" and "child" elements. Also there is nothing in your sample code that lets an element "expand its height 100%". Can you be more precise? And maybe post a **working** example, for example of jsfiddle.org

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific. Post edited! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This. I assume you want to put your .boxRight and .boxLeft in the .boxBottom

**The HTML**

```
<span class="infoBox"> <!--InfoBox Start-->
 <span class="boxTop"> <!--boxTop Start-->
 </span>               <!--boxTop End-->

 <span class="boxBottom"> <!--boxBottom Start-->
  <span class="boxLeft">  <!--boxLeft Start-->
  </span>                 <!--boxLeft End-->

  <span class="boxRight"> <!--boxRight Start-->
  </span>                 <!--boxRight End-->
 </span>                  <!--boxBottom End-->
</span>                   <!--InforBox End-->
```

**The CSS**

```
.boxTop
{
display: block;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.boxBottom
{
display: block;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```